# Tetrahedron with right dihedral angle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, solid-geometry

I am confused with this problem.

Consider a tetrahedron ABCD with one right dihedral angle. Show that the intersection of this tetrahedron with any plane perpendicular to an edge of the tetrahedron forms a right-angle triangle.

I can definitely imagine planes that are parallel to the base that don't form a right-angle triangle. What am I missing here?

Comment: What plane do you imagine?

Comment: The planes are perpendicular to an edge - how the parallel case is relevant?

Comment: I agree. a plane parallel to the base may not be perpendicular to the edge.

Comment: was the problem solved?